# Text after custom checkboxes isn't on baseline

Tags: html, css, input

In the following code:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" /> Pavement
<input type="checkbox" /> Dirt or rocky trails
<input type="checkbox"/> Gravel roads</p>
```

along with the following CSS:

```
h1, input, button, textarea, progress, p, a, ul, li {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #666;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 hsla(0,0%,100%,.75);
    margin: 10px 2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(0,0%,0%,.05), hsla(0,0%,0%,.01));
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 hsla(0,0%,100%,.5),
                0 1px 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.5);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

The checkboxes seem to be nearly one line about the other text. I tried removing *all* the CSS and the problem was resolved (the problem is also solved when I remove all the custom checkbox styling), but when I began to remove/replace the CSS line by line I couldn't find the problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd wrap the text following the inputs in a label tag and style those directly.

Comment: I suggest adding and fiddling with the CSS property `line-height` until you get it the way you want it. Try something like -8px first

Comment: I'm [not seeing it](http://jsfiddle.net/BLpks/) in Chrome. As you're describing it, I'm thinking that the 'Hello' should be a few pixels below the other text?

Comment: @jmeas Just looked at the jsfiddle. Do you not see the checkboxes nearly one line **above** the regular text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
margin: 10px 2px;
```

[Get rid of it and you're golden](http://jsfiddle.net/4x59m/)

Or, if you want to keep it on some elements but not your checkboxes and radio buttons, [you could do something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/4x59m/1/)

```
h1, input, button, textarea, progress, p, a, ul, li {
  ...
  margin: 10px 2px;
}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  ...
  margin: 0px 2px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `vertical-align: middle;` to your checkboxes should fix it.

i.e.

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
...
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This one works as well, and keeps the margins in place. Thanks to you too!